# when i try to read the pixel color of the center I got from cx and cy it says index out of pound

Tags: python, opencv

```py
for cnt in contours:
        peri=cv2.arcLength(contours[i],True)
        aprx=cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[i],0.04*peri,True)

        if len (aprx) >5:
                c=c+1
                M = cv2.moments(cnt)
                cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
                cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
                Areaa = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                print (image[cX,cY])

        if len (aprx)==4:
                squareM=cv2.moments(cnt)
                SX= int(squareM["m10"] / squareM["m00"])
                SY = int(squareM["m01"] / squareM["m00"])
                print("hehehe",SX,SY)

        i=i+1

cv2.imshow('img',image)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre], including the relevant parts of a potential stack trace. What is your actual _question_?

Answer (score 5):

In python `opencv` uses `numpy` as the matrix manipulation library, and indexing for images in `numpy` is `y` then `x`, so you should call `image[cY, cX]`.